# Concatenar variáveis vindas de um array

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso Concatenar variáveis de um array, para executar uma SQL, esse array pode ter valores diferenciados. Se o array for maior que 1, então deve ter $variavel + $variavel02. Se o array for igual a 1. Então joga apenas a variável.

```
$array_filial = array($f1, $f2, $f3, $f4);

$filiais = '';
foreach ($array_filial as $key => $f) {
      if ($f > 1) {
           $filiais .= "" . $f . "+ ";
      }
      else {
        $filiais .= "" . $f . "";
            }
}

$in_filial = substr($filiais, -0, -2);
```

Se array > 1

```
$in_filial = $f1 + $f2;
```

Se array = 1

```
$in_filial = $f1;
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT(CASE WHEN departamento = 1 AND tipo = 1 THEN (" . $in_filial . ") ELSE 0 END) as total from tabela;
```

Comment: tenta usar a função implode

Comment: esse seu código tem erro? qual??

Comment: Você quer somar todos os valores do array, correto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use implode()

```
if(count( $array ) == 1)
{
    $str = implode("+", $array);

}
```

Documentação: http://www.php.net/implode

Comment: Se eu entendi direito a pergunta, ele quer separar por "+" e não ",", de resto até concordo com o implode.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, mas era só utilizar a lógica e efetuar a troca, adaptar a realidade dele né @Dudaskank

Comment: Funciona, mas quando tem pelo menos 2 registros com dados

Comment: Com um único registro ele traz somente o mesmo

Answer (score 2):

A melhor solução para o teu problema seria usar a função [**implode()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)

exemplo usando implode():

```
if(count( $array ) == 1)
{
    $str = implode("+", $array);
}else{
    $str = $f1 . "+" . $f2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pra deixar mais genérico, tenta o *loop* assim:

```
$filiais = '';
foreach ($array_filial as $key => $f) {
      if ($filiais != '')
           $filiais .= "+ ";

      $filiais .= $f;
}
```

Comment: `$filiais = substr($filiais, 0, -2);`

Answer (score 1):

A função `implode()`, já citada pelos colegas, fará o serviço como você planejou.

Mas se eu entendi direito, você quer somar os valores do array para usar no seu SQL. Se não precisar ter os valores separados e puder fazer a soma antes, pode deixar o PHP fazer isso com a função [`array_sum`](http://docs.php.net/array_sum):

```
$in_filial = array_sum($array_filial);
```